# Creating a DLL for a group of .cpp, .h files

Tags: c++, dll

I have a legacy project, containing a bunch of .cpp, .h files. I want to create a DLL file for this entire project so that I can use it from Java code.

I am not sure how is it done. I found some tutorials on creatign DLL using visual studio, but they mostly create a brand new project.

Any input would help.

Comment: Have a look at `CMake` and `add_library` for how to create the DLL.

Comment: ***I found some tutorials on creatign DLL using visual studio, but they mostly create a brand new project*** You probably want to do that anyways. My advice is to create a simple dll that you can use and test with your java code before you even attempt to port your legacy project over to a dll. You will need some experience to be able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still would have a brand new project of API between your old code and application. And note that .dlls are limited in what they actually can do or can use. SO you may start with building new  .dll from scratch with function that represents the interface, then add your C++ code later.